# Add listener on tab close(collapse) in p:accordionPanel

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I tried to use the following listener on tab open event:

```
<p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{bean.onTabChange}"/>
```

But it doesn't handle the event when current tab is closed (collapsed).
Is there other way to workaround this?

I need an action event so that I know when the user actually closed the current tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for **Change Event** example on [primeface showcase for accordian panel](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/accordionPanel.xhtml).

There is **tabClose** event which you can use to register listener on current tab close :

```
<p:ajax event="tabClose" listener="#{bean.onTabClose}" />
```